# Rest API: Design URL and body for POST method and collection of IDs

Tags: c#, rest, restful-url

How to define a url and its html body for a post method according to Rest API?

Scenarios:

1 Send a message to a collection of clients based on client id.

Possible solution below:

```
url: POST message/clients

body
{
  "clientIds": "1,2",  //please note this is string due to scenario 2 below
   "Message":"hello" 
}
```

Using string instead of array is my concern.

2 Send a message to all clients

Possible solution below:

```
url: POST message/clients

body
{
  "clientIds": "ALL",
   "Message":"hello" 
}
```

2nd solution cannot reflect all clients on url, which is my concern.

Any better solution?

Comment: add a boolean flag "sendToAllClients", and have the clientIds as an array of Ids (int/string/Guid). get the values from clientIds, only when sendToAllClients is false

Comment: one of the options I considered, but it requires if condition too and one more field.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 methods

1 which accepts an array of ints (client ids)

1 which just accepts just the message

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It's all about your decision about how you want to manage it.

1. You may use an optional parameter.
2. You may pass an empty array. If array length is 0 then you assume it as all.
3. You may pass a special id like -999 or any other value which not supposed to be on your system and then you assume it as all.
4. you may add an extra boolean parameter to check is it for all? and then get value from the ids array.
   ..........

   ..........

   ..........

   And many more as per your business logic and data.